# print the diagonal of a matrix

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I used the awk command to print the diagonal

```
awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if (NR >= 1 && NR == i) print $(i - 0) }' matrix
```

and the output was like :

```
1
2
3
4
```

how can it be displayed like :

```
1
 2
  3
   4
```

matrix :

```
1 0 3 5 
0 2 6 7
3 0 3 5
8 7 2 4
```

Comment: you just forget to print 'empty' element before your element print so add `;else if (i < NR) printf( "  ")` before last  brace and it should work

Answer (score 0):

This may do:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (NR>=1 && NR==i) {for (j=1;j<=i-1;j++) printf " ";print $(i-0)}}' matrix
1
 2
  3
   4
```

Just add `i-1` number of space in front of line.

Or you can use a counter to make sure its independent of the line number, and tab.

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (NR>=1 && NR==i) {c++;for (j=1;j<=c-1;j++) printf "\t";print $(i-0)}}' matrix
1
        2
                3
                        4
```

Comment: @abinasunny `sed` is more a single line tool.  It may be a solution, but why not just stick to `awk` that works.  As far as  I have seen, if you have `sed` you also have `awk`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '1!G;h;:a;s/^(\s*)\S+\s*(.*)\n.*/ \1\2/;ta;s/^(\s*\S+).*/\1/' file
```

This uses the hold space to count the number of lines and hence the position of the field in the matrix.

A single space is used to replace the field(s) removed ahead of the field displayed and the once the field to be displayed is reached fields following it are removed.

To replace the space separator with a tab use:

```
sed -r '1!G;h;:a;s/^(\s*)\S+\s*(.*)\n.*/\t\1\2/;ta;s/^(\s*\S+).*/\1/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

With this InFile ...

```
1 0 3 5 
0 2 6 7
3 0 3 5
8 7 2 4
```

... this ***awk*** ...

```
awk '{for (j=1;j<=NF;j++) if (j!=NR) $j=""; print}' $InFile >$OutFile
```

... produced this OutFile ...

```
1   
 2  
  3 
   4
```

If you like to minimize keystrokes this works just as well ...

```
awk '{for (j=1;j<=NF;j++) j!=NR?$j="":1}1' $InFile >$OutFile
```

Daniel B. Martin

Answer (score 0):

with some shortcut (i put a output as string (%s) to be more exhaustif but (%d) is enough for $i printing and without replacing content of each element

```
awk '{ printf( "%" ( i++ * 2 ) "s%s\n", "", $i)}' YourFile
```